# How do you see all available repository solutions on Visual Studio 2017's Team Explorer Home panel?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

When connecting to a TFS server or git repository on VS 2015, you can see a list of available solutions in the Team Explorer Home panel:

[image: VS 2015 Team Explorer Home panel]

How can you get to a similar list on VS 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was a bug and was fixed with patch ['Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.06)'.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.1.26430.06)